# Trying to connect to a database created in a spring boot package with intelij Datagrip

Tags: database, eclipse, embedded, h2, datagrip

I have created a spring boot project in eclipse with a H2 embedded database and JPA. Inside my resource folder I'm using import.sql to populate the tables created in my entity package.The spring web application and database runs fine as I can check it but I want to know if it is possible to check this database in Intelij DataGrip like I can when I do this:

```
localhost:8080/h2-console
```

In my application.properties in my spring project I have this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./database/suppliersDB;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

In my Intelij Datagrip I add a data source H2 and give it the url and test connection and it says ok but doesn't show any of the tables and when I run a query in the DLL it says table doesn't exist

And I know I should probably shouldn't be using Intelij IDE since my project is in eclipse but it is just an experiment and it is frustrating me I can't get it working in Datagrip.

Also the embedded database file stored by eclipse is an .mv.db file which maybe the problem i'm not sure!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it because the database you created is in-memory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a change I can make to spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL

Comment: use url like `jdbc:h2:/path/to/file`

Comment: I have made edits to the question as I still have this problem with datagrip